# Unable to import Kibana Dashboards

Tags: templates, import, kibana

I'm trying to follow steps on this site:

https://miteshshah.github.io/linux/elk/how-to-monitor-system-with-elk-stack/

When it comes to loading the Kibana dashboards, It gives me an error.
Please see screenshot:
[image]

The code I'm trying to import is below:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "Gateway",
    "_type": "dashboard",
    "_source": {
      "title": "Gateway",
      "hits": 0,
      "description": "",
      "panelsJSON": "[{\"col\":1,\"id\":\"CPU0\",\"row\":1,\"size_x\":3,\"size_y\":2,\"type\":\"visualization\"},{\"col\":4,\"id\":\"CPU1\",\"row\":1,\"size_x\":3,\"size_y\":2,\"type\":\"visualization\"},{\"col\":7,\"id\":\"CPU2\",\"row\":1,\"size_x\":3,\"size_y\":2,\"type\":\"visualization\"},{\"col\":10,\"id\":\"CPU3\",\"row\":1,\"size_x\":3,\"size_y\":2,\"type\":\"visualization\"},{\"col\":1,\"id\":\"CPU4\",\"row\":3,\"size_x\":3,\"size_y\":2,\"type\":\"visualization\"},{\"col\":4,\"id\":\"CPU5\",\"row\":3,\"size_x\":3,\"size_y\":2,\"type\":\"visualization\"},{\"col\":7,\"id\":\"CPU6\",\"row\":3,\"size_x\":3,\"size_y\":2,\"type\":\"visualization\"},{\"col\":10,\"id\":\"CPU7\",\"row\":3,\"size_x\":3,\"size_y\":2,\"type\":\"visualization\"},{\"col\":1,\"id\":\"HDD\",\"row\":5,\"size_x\":3,\"size_y\":2,\"type\":\"visualization\"},{\"col\":4,\"id\":\"Memory\",\"row\":5,\"size_x\":3,\"size_y\":2,\"type\":\"visualization\"},{\"col\":7,\"id\":\"PS\",\"row\":7,\"size_x\":6,\"size_y\":2,\"type\":\"visualization\"},{\"col\":1,\"id\":\"Ping-Google\",\"row\":7,\"size_x\":6,\"size_y\":2,\"type\":\"visualization\"},{\"id\":\"System-Loadavg\",\"type\":\"visualization\",\"size_x\":6,\"size_y\":2,\"col\":7,\"row\":5}]",
      "version": 1,
      "timeRestore": true,
      "timeTo": "now",
      "timeFrom": "now-15m",
      "kibanaSavedObjectMeta": {
        "searchSourceJSON": "{\"filter\":[{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"analyze_wildcard\":true,\"query\":\"*\"}}}]}"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "CPU0",
    "_type": "visualization",
    "_source": {
      "title": "CPU0",
      "visState": "{\"type\":\"pie\",\"params\":{\"shareYAxis\":true,\"addTooltip\":true,\"addLegend\":true,\"isDonut\":false,\"spyPerPage\":10},\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"type\":\"sum\",\"schema\":\"metric\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"value\"}},{\"id\":\"2\",\"type\":\"filters\",\"schema\":\"split\",\"params\":{\"filters\":[{\"input\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"plugin_instance: '0'\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}}}}],\"row\":true}},{\"id\":\"3\",\"type\":\"terms\",\"schema\":\"segment\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"type_instance.raw\",\"size\":10,\"order\":\"desc\",\"orderBy\":\"1\"}}],\"listeners\":{}}",
      "description": "",
      "version": 1,
      "kibanaSavedObjectMeta": {
        "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"logstash-*\",\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}},\"filter\":[]}"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "CPU4",
    "_type": "visualization",
    "_source": {
      "title": "CPU4",
      "visState": "{\"type\":\"pie\",\"params\":{\"shareYAxis\":true,\"addTooltip\":true,\"addLegend\":true,\"isDonut\":false,\"spyPerPage\":10},\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"type\":\"sum\",\"schema\":\"metric\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"value\"}},{\"id\":\"2\",\"type\":\"filters\",\"schema\":\"split\",\"params\":{\"filters\":[{\"input\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"plugin_instance: '4'\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}}}}],\"row\":true}},{\"id\":\"3\",\"type\":\"terms\",\"schema\":\"segment\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"type_instance.raw\",\"size\":10,\"order\":\"desc\",\"orderBy\":\"1\"}}],\"listeners\":{}}",
      "description": "",
      "version": 1,
      "kibanaSavedObjectMeta": {
        "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"logstash-*\",\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}},\"filter\":[]}"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "CPU5",
    "_type": "visualization",
    "_source": {
      "title": "CPU5",
      "visState": "{\"type\":\"pie\",\"params\":{\"shareYAxis\":true,\"addTooltip\":true,\"addLegend\":true,\"isDonut\":false,\"spyPerPage\":10},\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"type\":\"sum\",\"schema\":\"metric\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"value\"}},{\"id\":\"2\",\"type\":\"filters\",\"schema\":\"split\",\"params\":{\"filters\":[{\"input\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"plugin_instance: '5'\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}}}}],\"row\":true}},{\"id\":\"3\",\"type\":\"terms\",\"schema\":\"segment\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"type_instance.raw\",\"size\":10,\"order\":\"desc\",\"orderBy\":\"1\"}}],\"listeners\":{}}",
      "description": "",
      "version": 1,
      "kibanaSavedObjectMeta": {
        "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"logstash-*\",\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}},\"filter\":[]}"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "CPU6",
    "_type": "visualization",
    "_source": {
      "title": "CPU6",
      "visState": "{\"type\":\"pie\",\"params\":{\"shareYAxis\":true,\"addTooltip\":true,\"addLegend\":true,\"isDonut\":false,\"spyPerPage\":10},\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"type\":\"sum\",\"schema\":\"metric\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"value\"}},{\"id\":\"2\",\"type\":\"filters\",\"schema\":\"split\",\"params\":{\"filters\":[{\"input\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"plugin_instance: '6'\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}}}}],\"row\":true}},{\"id\":\"3\",\"type\":\"terms\",\"schema\":\"segment\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"type_instance.raw\",\"size\":10,\"order\":\"desc\",\"orderBy\":\"1\"}}],\"listeners\":{}}",
      "description": "",
      "version": 1,
      "kibanaSavedObjectMeta": {
        "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"logstash-*\",\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}},\"filter\":[]}"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "CPU1",
    "_type": "visualization",
    "_source": {
      "title": "CPU1",
      "visState": "{\"type\":\"pie\",\"params\":{\"shareYAxis\":true,\"addTooltip\":true,\"addLegend\":true,\"isDonut\":false,\"spyPerPage\":10},\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"type\":\"sum\",\"schema\":\"metric\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"value\"}},{\"id\":\"2\",\"type\":\"filters\",\"schema\":\"split\",\"params\":{\"filters\":[{\"input\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"plugin_instance: '1'\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}}}}],\"row\":true}},{\"id\":\"3\",\"type\":\"terms\",\"schema\":\"segment\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"type_instance.raw\",\"size\":10,\"order\":\"desc\",\"orderBy\":\"1\"}}],\"listeners\":{}}",
      "description": "",
      "version": 1,
      "kibanaSavedObjectMeta": {
        "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"logstash-*\",\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}},\"filter\":[]}"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "CPU2",
    "_type": "visualization",
    "_source": {
      "title": "CPU2",
      "visState": "{\"type\":\"pie\",\"params\":{\"shareYAxis\":true,\"addTooltip\":true,\"addLegend\":true,\"isDonut\":false,\"spyPerPage\":10},\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"type\":\"sum\",\"schema\":\"metric\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"value\"}},{\"id\":\"2\",\"type\":\"filters\",\"schema\":\"split\",\"params\":{\"filters\":[{\"input\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"plugin_instance: '2'\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}}}}],\"row\":true}},{\"id\":\"3\",\"type\":\"terms\",\"schema\":\"segment\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"type_instance.raw\",\"size\":10,\"order\":\"desc\",\"orderBy\":\"1\"}}],\"listeners\":{}}",
      "description": "",
      "version": 1,
      "kibanaSavedObjectMeta": {
        "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"logstash-*\",\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}},\"filter\":[]}"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "CPU3",
    "_type": "visualization",
    "_source": {
      "title": "CPU3",
      "visState": "{\"type\":\"pie\",\"params\":{\"shareYAxis\":true,\"addTooltip\":true,\"addLegend\":true,\"isDonut\":false,\"spyPerPage\":10},\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"type\":\"sum\",\"schema\":\"metric\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"value\"}},{\"id\":\"2\",\"type\":\"filters\",\"schema\":\"split\",\"params\":{\"filters\":[{\"input\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"plugin_instance: '3'\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}}}}],\"row\":true}},{\"id\":\"3\",\"type\":\"terms\",\"schema\":\"segment\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"type_instance.raw\",\"size\":10,\"order\":\"desc\",\"orderBy\":\"1\"}}],\"listeners\":{}}",
      "description": "",
      "version": 1,
      "kibanaSavedObjectMeta": {
        "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"logstash-*\",\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}},\"filter\":[]}"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "CPU7",
    "_type": "visualization",
    "_source": {
      "title": "CPU7",
      "visState": "{\"type\":\"pie\",\"params\":{\"shareYAxis\":true,\"addTooltip\":true,\"addLegend\":true,\"isDonut\":false,\"spyPerPage\":10},\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"type\":\"sum\",\"schema\":\"metric\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"value\"}},{\"id\":\"2\",\"type\":\"filters\",\"schema\":\"split\",\"params\":{\"filters\":[{\"input\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"plugin_instance: '7'\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}}}}],\"row\":true}},{\"id\":\"3\",\"type\":\"terms\",\"schema\":\"segment\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"type_instance.raw\",\"size\":10,\"order\":\"desc\",\"orderBy\":\"1\"}}],\"listeners\":{}}",
      "description": "",
      "version": 1,
      "kibanaSavedObjectMeta": {
        "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"logstash-*\",\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}},\"filter\":[]}"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "PS",
    "_type": "visualization",
    "_source": {
      "title": "PS",
      "visState": "{\"type\":\"line\",\"params\":{\"shareYAxis\":true,\"addTooltip\":true,\"addLegend\":true,\"showCircles\":true,\"smoothLines\":true,\"interpolate\":\"linear\",\"scale\":\"linear\",\"drawLinesBetweenPoints\":true,\"radiusRatio\":9,\"times\":[],\"addTimeMarker\":false,\"defaultYExtents\":true,\"setYExtents\":false,\"yAxis\":{}},\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"type\":\"max\",\"schema\":\"metric\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"value\"}},{\"id\":\"2\",\"type\":\"date_histogram\",\"schema\":\"segment\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"@timestamp\",\"interval\":\"auto\",\"customInterval\":\"2h\",\"min_doc_count\":1,\"extended_bounds\":{}}},{\"id\":\"3\",\"type\":\"filters\",\"schema\":\"split\",\"params\":{\"filters\":[{\"input\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"collectd_type: 'ps_state'\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}}}}],\"row\":true}},{\"id\":\"4\",\"type\":\"terms\",\"schema\":\"group\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"type_instance.raw\",\"size\":10,\"order\":\"desc\",\"orderBy\":\"1\"}}],\"listeners\":{}}",
      "description": "",
      "version": 1,
      "kibanaSavedObjectMeta": {
        "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"logstash-*\",\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}},\"filter\":[]}"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "Ping-Google",
    "_type": "visualization",
    "_source": {
      "title": "Ping Google",
      "visState": "{\"type\":\"line\",\"params\":{\"addLegend\":true,\"addTimeMarker\":false,\"addTooltip\":true,\"defaultYExtents\":false,\"drawLinesBetweenPoints\":true,\"interpolate\":\"linear\",\"radiusRatio\":9,\"scale\":\"linear\",\"setYExtents\":false,\"shareYAxis\":true,\"showCircles\":true,\"smoothLines\":false,\"times\":[],\"yAxis\":{},\"spyPerPage\":10},\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"type\":\"avg\",\"schema\":\"metric\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"value\"}},{\"id\":\"2\",\"type\":\"date_histogram\",\"schema\":\"segment\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"@timestamp\",\"interval\":\"auto\",\"customInterval\":\"2h\",\"min_doc_count\":1,\"extended_bounds\":{}}},{\"id\":\"5\",\"type\":\"filters\",\"schema\":\"group\",\"params\":{\"filters\":[{\"input\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"collectd_type: \\\"ping\\\"\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}}}}]}},{\"id\":\"4\",\"type\":\"terms\",\"schema\":\"split\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"type_instance.raw\",\"size\":5,\"order\":\"desc\",\"orderBy\":\"1\",\"row\":true}}],\"listeners\":{}}",
      "description": "",
      "version": 1,
      "kibanaSavedObjectMeta": {
        "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"logstash-*\",\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"analyze_wildcard\":true,\"query\":\"*\"}},\"filter\":[]}"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "HDD",
    "_type": "visualization",
    "_source": {
      "title": "HDD",
      "visState": "{\"type\":\"pie\",\"params\":{\"shareYAxis\":true,\"addTooltip\":true,\"addLegend\":true,\"isDonut\":false},\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"type\":\"sum\",\"schema\":\"metric\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"value\"}},{\"id\":\"2\",\"type\":\"filters\",\"schema\":\"split\",\"params\":{\"filters\":[{\"input\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"plugin_instance: 'root'\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}}}}],\"row\":true}},{\"id\":\"3\",\"type\":\"terms\",\"schema\":\"segment\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"type_instance.raw\",\"size\":5,\"order\":\"desc\",\"orderBy\":\"1\"}}],\"listeners\":{}}",
      "description": "",
      "version": 1,
      "kibanaSavedObjectMeta": {
        "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"logstash-*\",\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}},\"filter\":[]}"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "Memory",
    "_type": "visualization",
    "_source": {
      "title": "Memory",
      "visState": "{\"type\":\"pie\",\"params\":{\"shareYAxis\":true,\"addTooltip\":true,\"addLegend\":true,\"isDonut\":false},\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"type\":\"sum\",\"schema\":\"metric\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"value\"}},{\"id\":\"2\",\"type\":\"filters\",\"schema\":\"split\",\"params\":{\"filters\":[{\"input\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"collectd_type: 'memory'\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}}}}],\"row\":true}},{\"id\":\"3\",\"type\":\"terms\",\"schema\":\"segment\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"type_instance.raw\",\"size\":5,\"order\":\"desc\",\"orderBy\":\"1\"}}],\"listeners\":{}}",
      "description": "",
      "version": 1,
      "kibanaSavedObjectMeta": {
        "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"logstash-*\",\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}},\"filter\":[]}"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "System-Loadavg",
    "_type": "visualization",
    "_source": {
      "title": "System Loadavg",
      "visState": "{\"type\":\"line\",\"params\":{\"shareYAxis\":true,\"addTooltip\":true,\"addLegend\":true,\"showCircles\":true,\"smoothLines\":false,\"interpolate\":\"linear\",\"scale\":\"linear\",\"drawLinesBetweenPoints\":true,\"radiusRatio\":9,\"times\":[],\"addTimeMarker\":false,\"defaultYExtents\":false,\"setYExtents\":false,\"yAxis\":{}},\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"type\":\"avg\",\"schema\":\"metric\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"longterm\"}},{\"id\":\"4\",\"type\":\"date_histogram\",\"schema\":\"segment\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"@timestamp\",\"interval\":\"auto\",\"customInterval\":\"2h\",\"min_doc_count\":1,\"extended_bounds\":{}}},{\"id\":\"5\",\"type\":\"filters\",\"schema\":\"split\",\"params\":{\"filters\":[{\"input\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"collectd_type: 'load'\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}}}}],\"row\":true}},{\"id\":\"6\",\"type\":\"avg\",\"schema\":\"metric\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"midterm\"}},{\"id\":\"7\",\"type\":\"avg\",\"schema\":\"metric\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"shortterm\"}}],\"listeners\":{}}",
      "description": "",
      "version": 1,
      "kibanaSavedObjectMeta": {
        "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"logstash-*\",\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}},\"filter\":[]}"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I'll appreciate if anyone can help me troubleshoot.

Comment: Do you have index-pattern `logstash-*` created in kibana? if yes, do you have field named `id` in your index-pattern `logstash-*`?

Comment: @avr
I actually don't have logstash-*. The only one's I have are below:

filebeat-*
geostore
packetbeat-*
topbeat-*
winglogbeat-*

Do I need to create logstash-* or can I use the one's I currently have?

Comment: When you are importing visualizations/dashboards you should have all indices on which those visualizations/dashboards are created. In your case all those vizs/dashboards were created on `logstash-*` index. So need to have `logstash-*` index with all fields mentioned in vizs.

Comment: Many thanks for getting back. If you don't mind me asking, can you please advise on how I can create and install the `logstash-*` index?

Comment: I suggest you to learn the basics of [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started.html) and [kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/getting-started.html).

Comment: Hi avr. I've setup the whole ELK stack and quite comfortable with it. However, would there be any specific steps that I can follow instead of going through a complete knowledge base of elasticsearch and kibana?

Comment: Let me know what are you trying to achieve at the end? Based on that I can provide some inputs!